# Best books on middlegame strategy?

Tags: strategy, theory, books, middlegame, pawn-structure

What are the best works trying to systematically summarize all middlegame themes and strategies: e.g. space advantage, pawn structures, exposed king, minority attack, isolated pawn, hanging pawns, etc. etc. I know of Euwe and Kramer two volumes work about the middlegame, but are there others, too? (PS no, I am not talking about Bronstein's Zurich 1953. Although it's a great book, I am speaking of a different kind of work.)

Answer (score 7):

The two books by John Watson about strategy. These themes are considered from a historical viewpoint usually in contrast to the way they are presented in textbooks. Even if you find a favorite textbook then later you should verify everything against John Watson's books because he always gives counterarguments and counterexamples to what is established as the usual course material.

Comment: +1, I was going to recommend 'Secrets of Modern Chess Strategy' too.

Answer (score 3):

These books are what I have studied about middle game strategy:

[My System--by Aron Nimzowitch this newer version is better than the original.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1880673851) A solid introduction to several of your topics. 
 
[Chess Fundamentals (Algebraic)--Jose Capablanca](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857440730)  A simple and clear book to read. 
[Art of Attack in Chess--Ladimir Vukovic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857444000) Clear and concise book to work through more of your "etc" topics. 
 
Yasser Seirawan's series of books from Winning Chess - Everyman Chess; there are some good ideas in them.
[The Art of Planning in Chess: Move by Move-- Grandmaster Neil McDonald](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/071349025X)  has some good insights from the opening.

Comment: I have read the books by Nimzowitsch. They are not good textbooks. They contain a lot of ill-justified claims but are very inspiring anyway. Definitely for someone already mature and looking for inspiration and a historical perspective. The John Watson books I mentioned in my answer refer to the writings of Nimzowitsch at appropriate moments.

Answer (score 3):

One should definitely mention John Nunn's amazing work on middlegames: [Understanding Chess Middlegames](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1906454272) is very well structured with regards to themes and strategies. The book is divided into main sections under which you may find dozens of subsections. Here is a list of main sections with crude descriptions:

1. *Material Imbalances:* exchange, two bishops vs. bishop and a knight, ...
2. *Strategy:* planning, improving piece position, ...
3. *Activity:* initiative, open files, ...
4. *Attacking Play:* common tactical motifs such as bishop sacrifices on king's flank, ...
5. *Defensive Play:* risks of attack, counter-attack, ...
6. *Pawn Structures:* isolated, doubled, hanging pawns, ...
7. *Typical Central Pawn Formations:* open, closed, half-open and formations arising from common openings, ...
8. *Typical Mistakes* common mistakes in the middlegame such as automatically accepting sacrifices, overvaluing slight advantages, ...

This was one of the best books I have read recently and I definitely recommend it for a structured approach to middlegame.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for Priyomes.

***Improve Your Chess Pattern Recognition: Key Moves and Motifs in the Middlegame***
 van de Oudeweetering, International Master Arthur

***Techniques of Positional Play: 45 Practical Methods to Gain the Upper Hand in Chess*** - Bronznik, Valeri

***100 Chess Master Trade Secrets: From Sacrifices to Endgames*** - Soltis, Andrew

Answer (score 1):

I still credit Ludek Pachman's trilogy "Complete Chess Strategy" for first making me understand any chess strategy. It was the difference for me between being an 1800, and when I became a Master.