How do I get over not wanting to move in my position?
I start the game, get through my opening, my knights are on good squares, bishops on diagonals and king is castled. Now in the early middle-game, my opponent (similarily rated to me) is not a computer so he and I continue making incremental moves. a6, h6 to prevent pins.
I don't want to push b5 now because what's the point. His bishop moves backwards to another diagonal.
Now what?
Unless my opponent makes an egregious error or a tactic, is this just chess apathy? I could just move my king 1 square back and forth, and so could my opponent. What's stopping that?

Link to similar question: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39185/what-is-the-best-way-to-play-the-middlegame

One might wonder whether the opening in question isn't the best for strategising and  making a plan from: e.g. if it's that classic giuoco pianissimo where all the pieces get developed but it's completely symmetrical and there's no obvious pawn break. Maybe another opening would be easier to play from. (If you've got an example game that would be useful.)

Once you've completed the opening, it's crucial to choose a new plan or continue with the existing one from opening. Just shuffling pieces back and forth leads to stagnation and allows your opponent to seize the initiative. Instead, you should valuate the position, identify weaknesses (your and opponent's), and look for opportunities to improve your position or disrupt your opponent's.
Plans often arise from openings, for example in exchange Spanish white wants to transition to pawn endgame, where he have 5 pawns to 4 on kingside. Meanwhile, Black wants to take advantage of Bishop pair.
